# How can I set up Borderlands to prevent blue and purple guns from spawning?

Tags: borderlands

I have three buddies that I farm Crawmerax with, but the legendary and pearlescent gear gets bogged down in the blue and purple crap. I have modded the .ini files to not have green and white dear but the blue stuff is just everywhere.

How can I set up Borderlands to prevent blue and purple guns from spawning?

Comment: Do you think you could clarify why you mean by the green and white dear, and the blue stuff being everywhere? Ive removed the part asking for a mod/tweak, as asking for mods is considered software recommendation, and off topic on arqade.

Comment: are you asking how to modify the game so Crawmerax only spawns legendary and pearlescent gear ?

Comment: Or is he asking for the game to filter out the proper rarity of weapons?  You can do that so only particular rarity of stuff are displayed.